# Update SQL table without creating duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using SQL Server and want to update a table with a certain condition. Here is the premise:

```
Feature:
ID  FeatureName  ApplicationId
1   Car          5
2   Car          6
3   Ship         5
```

```
Application:
ID  ApplicationName
5   Mobile
6   Server
```

Now I want to achieve two things:

1. If there would be a duplicate entry in the `Feature` table after the update then delete the old entry.
2. In the table `Feature` set `ApplicationId` to `6` (= `Server`) where the current `ApplicationId` is 5 (= `Mobile`).

So the final `Feature` table should look like this:

```
Feature:
ID  FeatureName  ApplicationId
2   Car          6
3   Ship         6
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You say you want 6 where the value is 5, but your result has 5 instead of 6.

Comment: @jarlh Of course, I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Feature SET ApplicationId = 6 WHERE ApplicationId = 5

DELETE FROM Feature
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(ID) as RowId, FeatureName, ApplicationId
   FROM Feature
   GROUP BY FeatureName, ApplicationId
)as KeepRows ON
   Feature.ID = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Update only has a license to modify exsiting records, and it can't remove or add anything normally.  I would suggest just doing your update along with a delete query in a single transaction:

```
UPDATE Feature
SET ApplicationId = 6
WHERE ApplicationId = 5

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, FeatureName, ApplicationId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FeatureName, ApplicationId ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM Feature
)

DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
update feature set applicationid = 6 where applicationid = 5;


delete from feature where id in (
    select min(id)
    from feature
    where featurename in
          (select featurename
          from feature f2 
          group by featurename
          having count(featurename) > 1)
    and applicationId in 
          (select applicationid 
          from feature f3
          group by applicationid
          having count(applicationId) > 1)
    group by featurename, applicationid;
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  F
SET  F.ApplicationId=(
case when F.ApplicationId=6 then (SELECT ID FROM  #Application S WHERE ID=5)
ELSE ApplicationId
END )
FROM #Feature F

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID, FeatureName, ApplicationId , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FeatureName ORDER BY ApplicationId) rn
FROM #Feature
)

DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE rn>1

SELECT * FROM #Feature
```